# How to change cputune dynamic?

Tags: kvm, libvirt, virsh

Can I change the `cputune` when VM is running?
I remember that there is a virsh command to change this parameter when VM is running.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

virsh vcpupin command can be used for pinning vcpus to host cpus on a running guest.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. Edited the answer.